# Django gettext not working properly with django rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, gettext

I'm having some weird bug with gettext while using a ModelSerializer, I cannot get the translated charfield choice for all of the choices, some choices work but others don't I even tried to run another `makemessages` command but the same inconsistent result.
this is the problematic field

```
status= models.CharField(
          max_length=50,
          default="pending",
          choices=[
              ('pending', _('Pending')),
              ('initiated', _('Initiated')),
              ('completed', _('Completed'))
          ]
      )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution to this was using `get_FieldName_display()` something like this worked correctly:

```
status = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_status(self, instance):
    from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
    return _(instance.get_status_display())
```

this is probably because i'm using windows :)